# Can outlook/teams add-in code be changed from the client application?

Tags: outlook, office-addins

I have the doubt: Can outlook add-in (created using yeoman generator as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator)) code be changed from the client application in browser or the app itself?

More precisely, let's say I am collecting user email through

```js
// cta-button handler
function action(event)
{
  axios.post('myurl', {email: Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress})
}
```

in `commands.js` file ([sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/outlook-tutorial#update-the-function-file-javascript)) and sending it to my backend api on some action event.

Can a user of the app modify the function in his browser/client app like this

```js
function action(event)
{
  axios.post('myurl', {email: 'someInvalidEmail@@abc.com.in'})
}
```

so that every time the add-in button is clicked my api receives invalid email?

I am not able to find answers in any docs.

Comment: Hello @Curious - Could you please elaborate your query and let us know what exactly you are trying to achieve.  Generally if you use yeoman generator, it will generate the code as per the provided feature capability and you can change or modify your code using Visual Studio Or Visual Studio Code Editor. I think, code can not be changed from the client application in browser or the app itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added some explanation. Is it ok now?

Comment: Modifying the function as asked above in browser/client app by app user doesn't seem to be feasible.